# Javascript two weird problems: POST not working, window.location.href not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, search

I created an instant search similar to google search using JQuery. The highlighted code doesn't work. It is weird since they work fine by its own and everything else works fine. Any idea why this is happening?
Q1.

searchq() works fine, but the createq() function doesn't work, and the variable txt could be posted to other files(search.php). However, the function createq() can't POST. It does get the global variable txt after testing, but the php file(create_object.php) can't get it no matter what POST method I used. Could anyone helps to write a bit POST code which can work in my code.

Q2
I want to create a function that,when the enter is pressed, the user will be redirected to the first search result(which is anchored with an url) . To achieve this, I create a function that variable redirectUrl got the anchored url as string, however, the redirect function window.location.href doesn't work, the page simply refreshed. I tested window.location.href function by its own in another file, it works though. It is so weird that my page simply refreshed, It even refreshed when I direct to google. window.location.href("www.google.com").

Note that I didn't include the connect to database function here. Coz I think the database username and password setting would be different to yours.So please create your own if you want to test it. The mysql is set with a table is called "objects", and it has one column named "name".

Thanks in advance!

```
 <html>
    <!-- google API reference -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- my own script for search function -->

    <center>
    <form method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="search" id="search" style="width:400px " placeholder="Search box" onkeyup="searchq();">
        <div id="search_output">
        </div>
    </form>
    </center>   

      <!-- instant search function -->
 <script type="text/javascript">

function searchq(){
        // get the value
            var txt = $("input").val();
            // post the value
            if(txt){
                $.post("search.php", {searchVal: txt}, function(result){
                    $("#search_output").html(result+"<div id=\"create\" onclick=\"creatq()\"><br>Not found above? Create.</div>");
                });
            }
            else{
                $("#search_output").html("");
            }


        };
function createq(){
    // allert for test purpose: test if the txt has got by the createq function
    alert(txt);
    **$.post( "create_object.php",{creatVal:txt} );**

}

// if enter key pressed, redirect page to the first search result
$("#search").keypress(function(evt){
    if (evt.which == 13) {
       // find the first search result in DOM and trigger a click event 
        var redirectUrl = $('#search_output').find('a').first().attr('href');
        alert(redirectUrl);
      **window.location.href = "www.google.com";
window.location.href = "www.google.com";**
    }
})

</script>
    </html>
```

PHP file (search.php)

```
 <?php
if(isset($_POST["searchVal"])){
    //get the search
    $search=$_POST["searchVal"];
    //sort the search
    $search=preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$search);
    //query the search
    echo "<br/>SELECT * from objects WHERE name LIKE '%$search%'<br/>";
    $query=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * from objects WHERE name LIKE '%$search%'") or die("could not search!");
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($query);
    //sort the result
    if($count==0){
        $output="there was no search result";
    }
    else{
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

            $object_name=$row["name"];

            $output="<div><a href='##'>".$object_name."</a></div>";
        }
    }
    echo $output;
}
?>
```

php file (create_object.php)

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST["createVal"])){
        $name=$_POST["createVal"];
        var_dump($name);

    }

?>
```

Comment: You should not post multiple questions as one question, it reduces your chance of getting an answer.

Comment: `**$.post` in the function `createq` - i guess there are errors in the console when you load the page

Comment: @RamRaider as I understand it, the stars are supposed to mark the highlighted code that is referred to in the question.

Comment: ah! I guess that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

In `createq()` you are trying to access the local variable `txt` that was defined in another function. If you declare a variable inside a function, only that function has access to the variable.

You can fix this by passing txt as an *argument* to createq. In order to do this, you need to call `createq` yourself instead of setting it as an event handler for a click event.

Use jqoery's .click() to add a proper event handler for the click event and from that handler call `createq`, passing along the value of `txt`. In order to set the click handler, you need a reference to the element with the id "create", that you currently don't have.

The solution to this particular problem looks something like this:

```
$.post("search.php", {searchVal: txt}, function(result){
    $("#search_output").html(result+"<div id=\"create\"><br>Not found above? Create.</div>");
    $("#search_output create").click(function() {
       createq(txt);
    });
});

...

function createq(txt){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

About the way page refresh. If DOM element with id of window.location.href is missing the page will refresh. For example 
 assume you have     window.location.href="#div1";
If DOM element with id="div1" is missing the page will surely refresh.